# How to enter vector inputs in SystemModelSimulate?

Tags: warning-messages, system-modeler, system-modeling

> A support case with the identification [CASE:4272760] was created.

---

I am having some difficulties to provide vector `inputs` for a Modelica model using Mathematica. To demonstrate this I am using a simple `block` that will pass a real vector of length 3 unchenaged to its output of the same dimension:

```
model = ImportString[
    "block VectorPassThrough
         input Real[3] u;
         output Real[3] y;
       equation
         y = u;
     end VectorPassThrough;"
   , 
   "mo"
];

model["ModelicaDisplay"]
```

[image: Modelica Code]

Now I would like to simulate this simple block and provide a vector input:

```
sim = SystemModelSimulate[ model, {"y"}, {0, 1}, Association[
   "Inputs" -> {
     "u" -> Function[ t, {1., 2., 3.}]
     }
   ]
]
```

Will throw the error `SystemModelSimulate::val` :

> The variables {u} were not recognized, or the types do not match the model.

Using a time Series also will not help:

```
sim = SystemModelSimulate[ model, {"y"}, {0, 1}, 
    Association[    
        "Inputs" -> {
            "u" -> TimeSeries[ { {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3} }, { {0, 1} }]
        }
    ] 
]
```

**In what format shall vector (and matrix) inputs be given for `SystemModelSimulate`?**

Comment: @MalteLenz Still hoping for a nice solution ... ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have received **answer from Technical Support at WRI**:

> *At present we cannot feed vectors as lists; instead we have to use array variables such as u[1], u[2] and so on.*
>
> [...]
>
> *The developers are currently working on implementing the feature for feeding vectors as lists.*

Since *arrays/vectors* can also be indexed using `enumerations` (e.g. "myEnumeration.first", "myEnumeration.second", ... ), having to address individual arguments in this way will be very cumbersome. Expanding the functionality of `SystemModelSimulate` would be very welcome.

**Update**

... but the most important reason for implementing vector input is, that in Modelica array dimensions can be left unspecified (e.g. `mat[:,:]`, `vec[:]`). We cannot simply assign a value to `vec[1]` because the Modelica compiler needs to be able to determine the dimensions form the dimensions of the input given. It would be really cumbersome, having to work around this using additional components like the [`Multiplex`](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/Modelica.Blocks.Routing.html).

Answer (score 1):

### Preliminary Solution for Vectors

Until we get what we deserve, here at least is a solution for vector input and output, which may be expanded:

```
vecOutput::usage = "vecOutput[\"var\", dim ] returns Sequence[\"var[1]\", \"var[2]\", ... , \"var[dim]\"]";
vecOutput[ var_String, dim_Integer ] := Sequence @@ Array[ var <> "[" <> ToString[#] <> "]" &, dim ]

vecInput::usage = "vecInput[ \"var\", { func1, func2, ... } ] returns Sequence[\"var[1]\" -> func1, \"var[2]\" -> func2, ...]"; 
vecInput[ var_String, funcList : { __Function } ] := Module[
    {
        varList = Array[ var <> "[" <> ToString[#] <> "]" &, Length @ funcList ]
    }
    ,
    Sequence @@ Thread[ varList ->  funcList ]
]

vecInput[ var_String, l_List ] := Module[
  { 
      varList = Array[ var <> "[" <> ToString[#] <> "]" &, Length @ l ],
      funcList = Map[ Function[t, #] & , l ]
  }
  ,
  Sequence @@ Thread[ varList ->  funcList ]
]

vecInput[ var_String, td_TemporalData ] /; td[ "PathCount" ] != 1 := With[ 
    { dim = td[ "PathCount"] }
    ,
    Module[
        {
            varList = Array[ var <> "[" <> ToString[#] <> "]" &, dim ],
            funcList = Array[ td[ "PathFunction", # ] &, dim ]
        }
        ,
        Sequence @@ Thread[ varList ->  funcList ]
    ]
]

vecInput[ var_String, ts_TemporalData ] /; ts[ "PathCount"] == 1 := With[ 
    { dim = ts[ "ValueDimensions"] }
    ,
    Module[
        {
            times = ts[ "Times" ],
            values = ts[ "Values" ]
        }
        ,
        vecInput[ var, TemporalData[ Transpose @ values, List @ times ] ]
    ]
]
```

We can now do the following:

```
vecInput[ "u", { 1, 2, 3} ] (* assign constant functions *)
```

to obtain

> `Sequence["u[1]" -> Function[t, 1], "u[2]" -> Function[t, 2]]`

For the simple model given in the OP we can then do:

```
sim = SystemModelSimulate[model, { vecOutput[ "y", 3 ] }, {0, 1},
    Association[
        "Inputs" -> { 
             vecInput[ "u", TimeSeries[ { {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3} }, { {0, 1} } ]  ] 
        }
    ]
]
```

> `SystemModelSimulationData[ ... ]`